# comma splice and type of phrase

Tags: american-english, british-english

*Rocking a massive clock around his neck*, he puts most rappers to shame.

He is now set to be released from category prison in Suffolk, *to a bail hostel after Christmas.*

Is the part after comma a noun phrase? How would you class the first example too?

**And are these all comma splices ?***

I've reorganzied the team, **now it's just a question of picking up from where we left off**

She was a huge star, **now she lives a normal life.**

“She has an attitude” you've heard someone say, **generally meaning that the person is negative or disagreeable or just has a bad outlook on life.**

Not here for the alcohol, **here to see an amazing band.**

Answer (score 1):

These are not comma splices; The phrase "Rocking a massive clock around his neck" could not be a complete sentence. Nor could "to a bail hospital in Suffolk"

The part about the bail hospital is a prepositional phrase acting to indicate the direction or outcome of the release.

The part about "Rocking a huge clock" is a participle phrase, describing how "he puts rappers to shame".

For the others, ask yourself "are both parts complete sentences?"  and "do both parts have a subject and a finite verb?"

I'll just note that in the last example, neither part contains a verb. It is an example of informal speech. We would understand it to mean "I'm not here for the alcohol...". but as informal speech whether it meets formal standards of punctuation are not really important.